# split layerSwitcher in differents divs outside the map using OpenLayer

Tags: openlayers

I'm having a map with a lot of layers full of poi. This POI are ordered by category (ie: food, sleep etc), and by sub category (ie: chinese restaurant, italian restaurant etc..).

I'd like  to have outside of my map a div for each category containing the list of subcategory buttons that shows/hides the corresponding layer.

For now, all I manage to do is display the layer switcher in a lonely div.

```
layerSwitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('customlayerswitcher')});
```

Your help will be greatly appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to reuse the layer switcher but as OpenLayers is fully JavaScript you can do whatever you want. Hide those POI layers from the layer switcher (displayInLayerSwitcher : false) and handle the adding/removing of items into category divs yourself via JavaScript. Handle user clicks and according actions to do in OpenLayers (hide/show layer).